# Object Storage - Can't access container in region "London"

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I have created a contained through dashboard in region "London". But when I try to access it, the program checks -apparently as default region as also stated [here](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BluePic)- only the region "Dallas" even though the region in my credentials is "London". I tried to create a container through my program and the container was created in the region "Dallas".

How can I make my program access the container in region "London"? Any advice on how to specify the region is appreciated.

My code to list containers looks like below;

```
final private OSClient os;

public ObjectStorageDAO(String url, String userId, String password, String project, String domainName)
        throws Exception {

    Identifier domainIdentifier = Identifier.byName(domainName);
    Identifier projectIdentifier = Identifier.byName(project);

    os = OSFactory.builderV3().endpoint(url).credentials(userId, password)
            .scopeToProject(projectIdentifier, domainIdentifier).authenticate();
}

/**
 * Returns the list of containers under the account
 */
public List containers() {
    return os.objectStorage().containers().list();
}
```

Comment: after initiating the `os` object, can you try forcing the region?  E.g. `os.useRegion('london')` - http://www.openstack4j.com/learn/identity/identity-v3

Comment: Thank you very much @SHC

Comment: Great stuff - I've added this as an answer.  Would you be ok to accept this answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After initiating the os object, can you try forcing the region?

```
final private OSClient os;

public ObjectStorageDAO(String url, String userId, String password, String project, String domainName)
        throws Exception {

    Identifier domainIdentifier = Identifier.byName(domainName);
    Identifier projectIdentifier = Identifier.byName(project);

    os = OSFactory.builderV3().endpoint(url).credentials(userId, password)
            .scopeToProject(projectIdentifier, domainIdentifier).authenticate();

    /////////////////////////
    // force london region //
    /////////////////////////

    os.useRegion('london')
}

/**
 * Returns the list of containers under the account
 */
public List containers() {
    return os.objectStorage().containers().list();
}
```

For more information, see here: http://www.openstack4j.com/learn/identity/identity-v3